# How do I dump a list of imported property sheets from MSBuild

Tags: msbuild

I am constructing a hierarchy of property sheets (many that are conditionally included according to Platform and Configuration) and I am attempting to write a set of targets that can help diagnose any errors that may sneak in.

What I would like is a list of property sheets that have been included.

Example:

```
<ImportGroup Condition="$(Configuration.Contains('Debug'))">
  <Import Project="ps.cpp.config.debug.props"/>
</ImportGroup>
<ImportGroup Condition="$(Configuration.Contains('Release'))">
  <Import Project="ps.cpp.config.release.props"/>
</ImportGroup>

<ImportGroup Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'x64'">
  <Import Project="ps.cpp.plat.x64.props"/>
</ImportGroup>
<ImportGroup Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'Win32'">
  <Import Project="ps.cpp.plat.win32.props"/>
</ImportGroup>
```

And a target like this:

```
<Target Name="DumpPropertySheets">
  <!-- This doesn't work! -->
  <!-- <Message Text="%(Import.Project)"/> -->
</Target>
```

Which should result in console output like this when built with `msbuild test.vcxproj /t:DumpPropertySheets /p:Platform=x64 /p:Configuration:Debug`

```
DumpPropertySheets:
  ps.cpp.config.debug.props
  ps.cpp.plat.x64.props
```

Comment: Also, I'd like it if someone could create an msbuild-batching tag since obviously my attempt at batching on something other than an ItemGroup obviously failed.  I still think it is a useful tag to have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not an obvious way to do what you are trying to do.  Imports are pre-processed to aggregate all of the content into a single file, they are not a datatype like item arrays or properties that can be referenced later on.

The syntax %(Import.Project) doesn't work because that syntax is valid only for item arrays, and you are trying to use it on the *Import* keyword, which is not a populated item array.

Also note that your use of the ImportGroup elements surrounding the imports is optional (and probably a bit verbose).  The following two constructs in an MSBuild file are equivalent...

```
<ImportGroup Condition="$(Configuration.Contains('Debug'))">
   <Import Project="ps.cpp.config.debug.props"/>
</ImportGroup>
```

...and (line-wrapped for clarity)...

```
<Import
   Condition="$(Configuration.Contains('Debug'))"
   Project="ps.cpp.config.debug.props" 
   />
```

If you are trying to diagnose property sheet import errors, don't forget about the /pp command-line switch, which will dump the complete preprocessed file.  You also could (for your own files at least) give each import a unique entry into an item array, e.g.

```
<Import
   Condition="$(Configuration.Contains('Debug'))"
   Project="ps.cpp.config.debug.props" 
   />
```

then inside `ps.cpp.config.debug.props`,

```
<ItemGroup>
   <_Import Include="$(MSBuildThisFile)" />
</ItemGroup>
```

then later in your build you could get what you appear to be looking for, to some degree, with,

```
<Target Name="DumpPropertySheets">
   <!-- This does work! -->
   <Message Text="%(_Import.Identity)" />
</Target>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reponse.  Your solution of defining an ItemGroup within each property sheet is the solution that I had sniffed out before.  I've gone ahead with that technique for the moment.  Although, in some of my experimentation, the $(MSBuildThisFile) property was empty when I was inside an imported project, so I reverted to hardcoding the filename.  I'll wait for more responses before I accept your answer as I'd like to see if anyone else has any techniques that are less maintenance.

Comment: Also, the reason that I placed the Condition on the ImportGroup element and not the Import element is due to a reported bug in Visual Studio where it fails to properly handle configuration switch and conditionalized Import elements.  It seems that conditionalizing ImportGroup works in my environment.  See the Note at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92x05xfs.aspx